# OpenCV linking error

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

The same error first occured in the middle of the build when linking another shared library. Then I've added BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF  so now it occurs at the very end only. The last two options were also added in hope of fixing it. Using LinuxMint 17.

```
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/deblurring.cpp.o
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/videostab/CMakeFiles/opencv_videostab.dir/src/motion_stabilizing.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library ../../lib/libopencv_videostab.a
[ 99%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 99%] Generating pyopencv_generated_include.h, pyopencv_generated_funcs.h, pyopencv_generated_types.h, pyopencv_generated_type_reg.h, pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python2
[ 99%] Building CXX object modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libavformat.a(allformats.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `ff_a64_muxer' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
//usr/local/lib/libavformat.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/serj/work/beautytorch/venv/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF  \
-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC \
-D WITH_IPP=OFF \
..
```

Comment: Why `-D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC` ?

Comment: Because "recompile with -fPIC" in the error message... not sure of correct

Answer (score 0):

It is `ffmpeg` which should have been compiled with `-fPIC`. [enter link description here](https://github.com/Alexey-Yakovenko/deadbeef/issues/1691) I had `ffmpeg` compiled from sources. After deinstallation, `opencv` links fine.